# Discussion on meta, can I ask a question in an answer?

Tags: discussion

So this is a bit awkward as this somehow a meta-meta question. I recently found myself wondering about a particular thing and found that there already is a corresponding question on meta. However I found that the discussion and the answers were not really what I was looking for. I would have liked to raise a specific point which was (to my liking and probably also in character count) too long to be put into a comment to either question or answer.

Now my question is: rather than duplicating the question is it acceptable to ask a question in an answer, basically elaborating on the original question or should I ask my question separately, highlighting the fact that it is a special case or an eloboration on an existing question?

Comment: To ask a new question, ask a new question, like Chris says. But if you want to ask for clarification on a question, or about special cases, you can write a comment, to either the question or to one of the answers.

Comment: *sigh* Just when we got over the MSE/MSO split, we need another meta.meta.SO split? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not acceptable to ask a question in an answer.

If you have a new question ask it as a new question and reference the original question/answer in your new question.